# Admob ads will not show real ads but will show test ads

Tags: swift, admob, xcode10

So for about a week my real ads were working. I was finishing up my app and went to upload to the app store. I had to change my bundle ID and team to my account linked to the developers program to be able to upload to the app store. I got the error that it was no longer linked to admob or firebase because of the different bundle ID. I have relinked admob and firebase to the project. Gotten the new googleServices-info file and uploaded that as well into my program. However, the tests ads are still showing but not real ads. I have tried some solutions to similar problems as well as waiting for a couple of days, I have also tried making new ads to get a different ID code with and no luck in either. When running on my iphone the only message I get is "  To get test ads on this device, set: request.testDevices = @[ @"mytestID" ];"